# Proving that the set of continuous linear maps (From a Banach space $X$ to another Banach space $Y$) is an open subset of $L(X,Y)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I am a university undergraduate student, and I am reading up on the German Functional Analysis textbook "Introduction to Functional Analysis" by Friedrich Hirzebruch/Winfried Scharlau.

My question goes in this manner:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. Prove that the set of continuous
>   bijective linear maps from $X\to Y$ is an open subset of $L(X,Y)$
>   (with respect to the sup norm, defined by
>   $||T||=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{||Tx||}{||x||}$).

As for the theorems that are involved, I think the "Open mapping theorem" and its corollary, "The theorem of the inverse operator" might be useful, but I could not think of even a way to even start with tackling the problem, not even with the hint:

> Consider $T$ $\in$ $L(X)$  with $||T||$ sufficiently small. Does the
>   identity $(\operatorname{Id}-T)^{-1}=T^0+T^1+T^2+\dots$ holds?

And extensive searches with the internet/google along with various textbooks doesn't help for me.

Therefore, I humbly ask for help in solving this question. Further hints to point me out in the right way would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your notation, are elements of $L(X,Y)$ bounded?

Comment: Yes. Like what @Jan said and to add on: an element f of $L(X,Y)$ is bounded iff f is continuous iff f is continuous at a point.

Comment: Yes, I was confused by the title.

Comment: For next time: you want to show a statement of the form $\forall S\in GL(X,Y),\ldots$ where the ... stand for the existance of some ball in your candidate for an open set. It's almost always good to consider examples first. In particular for $S=Id$, the given hint tells you what to do. Then the general case follows by a simple shift argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I denote with $\operatorname{GL}(X,Y)$ the set of continuous (and therefore bounded) invertible linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. We first show the following Lemma:

> If $A \in L(X)$ such that $\| A \| < 1$,  then  $I - A \in \operatorname{GL}(X)$ (where $I$ denotes the identity on $X$) and $(I - A)^{-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty A^k$.

*Proof therefore.* By the submultiplicativity of the operator norm we have $\| A^k \| \leq \|A\|^k$ and therefore

$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \| A \|^k \stackrel{\|A\| < 1}{=} \frac{1}{1 - \|A\|}$$

using geometric series. Using Weierstraß-M-test it follows that $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty A_k$ is an absolutely convergent series in the Banach space $L(X)$ and in particular, $B := \sum_{k = 0}^\infty A^k$ is well-defined in $L(X)$. One easily sees $AB = BA = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty A^k$, therefore we also have $(I - A)B = B(I - A) = I$ and this is equivalent to $(I - A)^{-1} = B$.

Now we prove our desired result:

> The set $\operatorname{GL}(X, Y)$ is open in $L(X, Y)$.

*Proof.* Let $T_0 \in \operatorname{GL}(X, Y)$ and $T \in L(X, Y)$ such that $\| T_0 - T \| < \|T_0^{-1}\|^{-1}$. Also,

$$T = T_0 + T - T_0 = T_0 [I + T_0^{-1} (T - T_0)].$$

We want to show that $I + T_0^{-1}(T- T_0) \in \operatorname{GL}(X)$. Since

$$\| - T_0^{-1}(T - T_0)\| \leq \|T_0^{-1}\| \| T - T_0 \| <1$$

this follows from our preceding Lemma. All in all, we have shown that the open ball in $L(X, Y)$ with center $T_0$ and radius $\|T_0^{-1}\|^{-1}$ is an element of $\operatorname{GL}(X,Y)$, so the proof is complete.

Comment: Wow! I have to admit, that I would not have thought of this proof myself, both on the lemma and on the main part of the result. Thank you for your help! This question is indeed very hard for my standard. >.<

One question though:, in the main part of the proof, in order to invoke the Lemma, do we have to show that $-T_0^{-1}(T- T_0)$ has to be in $L(X,X)$ (as a prerequisite for the lemma) such that the rest of the proof follows through?

Comment: @Crimsonfirebird Probably yes, you're right, I did not mention this. But this should be clear, since you know $T - T_0 \in L(X, Y),\ -T_0^{-1} \in L(Y, X)$ and the composition of linear maps is linear, so $-T_0^{-1}(T - T_0) \in L(X, X)$. By the way - I would recommend you the Analysis-books of Amann/Escher. They prove everything. In particular, you will find this proof in part II.

Comment: I have checked the book (From illegal sources of course) and indeed, it is in part II, under Proposition 7.2.

The trinity looks to be a promising reference to add to my collection. Thanks for the recommendation!